# Huygens' Principle and Ocean Waves

Tags: waves, huygens-principle

Ocean waves can travel in any direction, but waves breaking on the sea-shore are usually approximately parallel to the line of the beach. How can Huygens' principle explain this phenomenon? Does it have something to do with the fact that the velocity of the waves decreases as the water gets shallower?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, I think you should reconsider as this seems to me a hard question. I tried but failed to come up with a quantitative description of how changing water depth might *parallelise* wave direction. I doubt Huygen's principle would apply because I don't think much energy is reflected from the shore (at least not from a beach - you might get reflection from a harbour wall). I would have guessed wave direction was mostly a function of wind direction, but I have to concede that in my experience waves, or at least their crests, are frequently parallel to the beach.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. In deep water the speed of an ocean wave is approximately independent of the depth. But in shallow water (a working definition is the depth is much smaller than the wavelength), the wave speed is proportional to the square root of the depth (see for example [What determines the speed of waves in water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121327/what-determines-the-speed-of-waves-in-water/121330#121330) ).

You can then extend this to an optics analogy (and Huygens principle) by noting that as the wave speed decreases towards the shore (shallower depth), that is equivalent to increasing the refractive index of the water. So you can imagine the wave propagating at some angle to the shore being "refracted" such that its propagation direction is diverted towards being more towards perpendicular to the shoreline (or at least towards where the gradient of depth is largest).

To use Huygen's principle in this case, you could divide the water up into strips, parallel to the shore, each with its own refractive index (increasing towards the shore). Then apply the usual Huygen's wavelet construction that is used to prove Snell's law at each interface between two media with different refractive indices.

Comment: The fact that waves in shallow water approach the boundary at a normal angle is due to Snell's law. I don't understand what this has to do with Huygen's principle.

Comment: @NickP And how do you derive Snell's law! It can be done in several ways, but one of them (and probably the most often met at an elementary level) is using Huygen's principle. For example http://www.saburchill.com/physics/chapters2/0012.html or here http://www.pstcc.edu/departments/natural_behavioral_sciences/Web%20Physics/Chapter038.htm or many others.

Comment: Fair enough - I stand corrected. Thank you for adding the buzzword "Snell" to your solution, as for water waves people like me it greatly clarifies your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the Huygens principle is applicable to waves on the surface of liquid, as the principle is only valid in spaces with an odd number of dimensions (http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath242/kmath242.htm).

Comment: isn't this better off as a comment?

Comment: @glance: Comments can be deleted any moment, and I believe my answer is relevant: it looks like the Huygens principle cannot explain the phenomenon for the simple reason that the principle is not applicable.