# Why do water waves with longer wavelengths travel faster?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, dispersion

When wind blows over the sea, it excites a range of wavelengths.

Why do longer wavelengths travel faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Definitions**

- *deep water limit* : when the wavelength of the mode/wave is much less than the depth of the water
- [*shallow water limit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations) : when the wavelength of the mode/wave is much larger than the water depth

## **Answer**

> Why do longer wavelengths travel faster?

In the deep water limit, the phase speed of, say, a [gravity wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) is $V_{ph} \propto \sqrt{\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength.  This is because the waves are [dispersive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(water_waves)), i.e., their frequency depends upon their [wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber)/[wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelength).

Comment: I wrote a longer answer to a similar question here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121327/what-determines-the-speed-of-waves-in-water/121330#121330

Comment: @NickP Maybe for the same reasons a moving point (boat ) in water creates waves  with longer wavelengths the faster it moves

Comment: @veronika how is that so? the wavelengths change as a function of their distance from the source in that case.

Comment: @veronika: I think you might have it backward. For sailboats with displacement hulls, the length of the waterline determines the wavelength of the wave it generates, and that affects the maximum speed the boat can go.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey. So is it false that the lesser the velocity of the sailboat the lesser the wavelength it creates?