# Why wavelength increases away from the source of a water ripple?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, waves

[image]

Hi readers, I have been thinking why the wavelength of water as it gets farther from the source since **V=frequency*wavelength**. This means that if it g**ets farther way**, the **wavelength increases which means increase in velocity of wave**. However, the **velocity should decrease** as you get further from the source right?

Comment: Well explained in the video [Ripples in a pond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dESm6VjfSNs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do water ripples widen (in plain English)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189226/why-do-water-ripples-widen-in-plain-english)