# Does a circular surface water wave decrease by 2$\pi$r?

Tags: waves, intensity

Does the energy of a wave in water decrease by (2$\pi$)r?

If that is right, why do we see waves at a considerable distance of almost same intensity of the near ones?

[image]

Comment: The picture shows a standing wave solution, i.e. energy is reflected back from the bounds of the circular  pond.

Comment: @annav no, it's a running cylindrical (well polar) wave. But anyway, one shouldn't base their physical intuition on videogame-generated images. It's better to look at real waves in the real water reservoirs.

Comment: Here is what ripples on a pond really look like. http://youtube.com/watch?v=dESm6VjfSNs

Comment: @Ruslan this does not exclude the solution to be a standing wave,  but is it a videogame?

Comment: @annav it can't be a standing wave, since the pond is obviously non-circular. And even if its borders are, there are multiple obstacles, which would drastically change the eigenfunctions. Finally, how could this be a standing wave if there's an obvious splash? And yes, the graphics is too unrealistic to think that it's a photo.

Comment: a similar question answered here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1289/

Comment: energy is proportional to the length of the wave by huygen's principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *surface wave* spreading from a sinusoidal point source over a lossless and dispersion-free medium will indeed spread as $\propto \frac{1}{r}$. This follows easily from energy conservation: because the geometry has circular symmetry the instantaneous power $p(\rho,\phi)$may depend only on $\rho$ and not $\phi$ thus the total power integrated over circle of radius $r$ is constant is then $2\pi r p(r)=P_0$ and thus $p(r)=\frac{P_0}{2\pi r}$where $P_0$ is the power of the source. As is normally the case $p \propto a^2$ where $a$ is the amplitude of the wave, one has that $a(r) \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$
(A similar same argument shows the $\propto \frac {1}{r^2}$ power spreading in the 3D spherically symmetric case.)

In the case of gravity waves the situation is complicated by the fact that the surface waves are dispersive. Consequently if instead of a periodic source we have an impulse like excitation, such as a stone dropped, the elementary waves of different frequency will travel with different velocity and the wavefront will break apart: the longer wavelengths travel faster and leave behind the smaller wavelength components. The result is that the wavefront amplitude is no more $\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$ but it also depends on the bandwidth and frequency distribution of the excitation.

Comment: But it's required that we show that two waves with the same length have the same energy regardless of curvature. The argument using circular symmetry  is interesting but i think it needs to be developed. You describe how the energy is proportional to the height squared but that's not relevant to the question is it?

Comment: @rpfphysics I do not know what is or is not required, and I do not understand what two waves you are referring to. I only reacted to the question "Does the energy of a wave in water decrease by (2π)r?".  As I said above it depends on if the wave is a pure sinusoid or not.  The height is relevant in the sense that to calculate how the wavepacket spreads you need Fourier transformation of the *amplitude* distribution.

Comment: but basically, all i'm saying is that just because the energy of the wave is proportional to the square of the amplitude, it doesn't mean that it is inversely proportional to the distance across which it spread

Comment: and the second statement is what is required i guess